# Postman - disable auto-append parameters in URL

Tags: request, postman

When I use Postman's  parameters field, the parameters are automatically appended to URL...

[image]

However, I dont want that way.. I use POST method, so no need URL to be changed... How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. Just don't add your keys to the parameters.

Instead, add the keys to the body request.

You can use 2 methods to to it: `form-data` and `x-ww-form-urlencoded` 
[image]